# An exception with == vs is?

Tags: python, operator-keyword

From what I understand, the `==` operator checks if two variables are equal, while the `is` operator checks if two variables have the same identity/ reference the same object. So why is `print(id(a) is id(b))` `False` ? Don't the two variables reference the same integer?

```
a = 1000000000
b = 1000000000

print(id(a))           #182798416
print(id(b))           #182798416
print(id(a) is id(b))  #False
print(id(a) == id(b))  #True
print(182798416 is 182798416) #True
```

Comment: it's an integer object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` function returns a new integer object, each time, so the integer objects are not the same.

Comment: yes, but interning of integers can make `is` work with low values from -5 to 256 IIRC.

Comment: So the function returns different integer objects. In this case it just so happens that the integers are the same, but the objects are not?